# How can I format SD card in android application programmatically?

Tags: android, format, sd-card

How can i format the SD card inside the mobile by implementing the code for "formatting SD card" in an application?
im currently using this code, but i cant get it to work.

```
    public void wipingSdcard(View view) {
        File deleteMatchingFile = new File(Environment
                .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());
        try {
            File[] filenames = deleteMatchingFile.listFiles();
            if (filenames != null && filenames.length > 0) {
                for (File tempFile : filenames) {
                    if (tempFile.isDirectory()) {
                        wipeDirectory(tempFile.toString());
                        tempFile.delete();
                    } else {
                        tempFile.delete();
                    }
                }
            } else {
                deleteMatchingFile.delete();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void wipeDirectory(String name) {
        File directoryFile = new File(name);
        File[] filenames = directoryFile.listFiles();
        if (filenames != null && filenames.length > 0) {
            for (File tempFile : filenames) {
                if (tempFile.isDirectory()) {
                    wipeDirectory(tempFile.toString());
                    tempFile.delete();
                } else {
                    tempFile.delete();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And i am also using android:onClick="wipingSdcard" in my xml.code for the "format sd card" button.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Did you include permissions ?

Comment: Yes, im using these:
WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
STORAGE and
READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE @RahulShaw

Comment: Please explain, **completely and precisely**, what "i cant get it to work" means.

Comment: I have connected the first method to a button on the application.. When i press the button, the sd card isnt being formatted. @CommonsWare

Comment: Your code assumes that `toString()` called on a `File`, with that string later used with the `File` constructor, gives you the same `File` back. I would not assume this. And, besides, it is wasteful. Simply pass the `File` into `wipeDirectory()` and use it. Or, use [an even more efficient algorithm](http://pastebin.com/PqJyzQUx). None of this has anything to do with "formatting", as formatting is not the same as deleting all files.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have searched a lot over the internet. I didn't get the answer whether we can programmatically format SD Card or not. I got the piece of code which just delete files from SD Card but can be recovered from recovery software. Do we have the option to format SD Card programmatically?

Comment: @AmanSrii: There is nothing in the Android SDK for formatting removable storage, AFAIK.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you cannot format an SD Card by deleting all of its files and folders. Imagine that SD Card is unformatted, you can't just delete the files inside it, because the operating system doesn't know what filesystem it uses.

Answer (score 0):

Include these permissions, too.

`MOUNT_FORMAT_FILESYSTEMS`

`MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS`

Comment: i did add these permissions.. but still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Does
    wipeDirectory(tempFile.toString());
give the right parameter?

I mean, is tempFile.toString() the same as tempFile.getPath().toString() ?
It could be this.

Comment: I have added getPath() to the parameter, still not working.
I also changed Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() to Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
Still not working.. Maybe the path is different on Sony phones? Im using a Sony phone for testing via ADB mode

Comment: What did you try already? does deleting a specific file work? (@user3428781) like File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString(),"asdf.txt"); f.delete();